# Make space between buttons when assigning their width and height programmatically

Tags: java, android, layout

Im assigning the width and height of buttons in a Linear Layout(that has gravity set to center_horizontal) programmatically by getting the screen width.

How can I make a space-say 15px between each button-somewhat what android does to its default buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide margin on buttons from left and right as required, Like below code

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Depending on what layout you are using choose one of them

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
```

or

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams
```

Comment: is it possible to do it in xml?

Comment: you can also do this by xml but you need to provide width of button as little bit less from half of the screen width as you are calculating so that margin can work

Comment: I tried the above and it worked, thanks! Also didnt understand the last part of your previous comment

Comment: Means if you are providing the width of buttons as half of the width of screen then buttons will cover the full screen width.Now if you will provide margin then there is no space left for that margin, That's why you should provide button width little bit(like 5px) less so that 5 px margin can be provide to buttons.